# SailsJS get posted data

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I've tried getting the post data in my controller actions using the following:

```
req.body.name
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

you can try to access them by first retrieving them all

```
function(req, res, next) {
    var params = req.params.all();
    //then you can access them like this...
     console.log(params.name)
  }
```

Comment: this one is quite useful since it fetches all fields from req.params, req.query and req.body. I usually put this in the beginning of all controller actions

Answer (score 0):

If you input-field have the name "name" you can do:

```
req.param("name")
```

See: http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Request/req.param.html

Answer (score 0):

Try req.allParams() to try to find it in the variable structure. You might have it misspelled somewhere or something else amiss. 
http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Request/req.allParams.html